# ¿Como resolver "structure of query does not match function result type" en postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Estoy usando PostgreSQL

He creado este procedimiento almacenado:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getPosts(current_rows integer,limit_recoords integer) RETURNS SETOF evento AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT evento."titulo",evento."fechaPublicacion",evento."contenido" FROM evento ORDER BY evento."fechaPublicacion" DESC OFFSET current_rows LIMIT limit_recoords;
END; $$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Quiero que devuelva las filas de la tabla evento, pero al llamar al procedimiento obtengo el siguiente error:

```
ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type
DETAIL:  El tipo retornado character varying(300) no coincide con el tipo de registro esperado integer en la columna 1.
CONTEXT:  función PL/pgSQL getposts(integer,integer) en la línea 3 en RETURN QUERY
SQL state: 42804
```

No comprendo que tengo mal, ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Answer (score 3):

El tipo de retorno estaba malo, como deseaba retornar filas de una tabla debí especificar `table` con las columnas de la tabla que la consulta dentro de mi funcion retornan.

```
CREATE FUNCTION getPosts(current_rows  bigint,limit_recoords bigint) RETURNS TABLE(titulo character varying(300),contenido text,fechaPublicacion date) AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT evento."titulo",evento."contenido",evento."fechaPublicacion" FROM evento ORDER BY evento."fechaPublicacion" DESC OFFSET current_rows LIMIT limit_recoords;
END; $$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Comment: Recuerda que puedes marcar como aceptada tu solución y así el resto conocerla

Comment: Y qué pasa en los casos en los que quieres regresar un tipo pero no todas las columnas?

Comment: Hola! Si aun no es tarde me gustaria preguntar, mi consulta devuelve todas la columnas de su tabla, todos los campos les quiero devolver e hice un inner join por lo que los campos son varios, para devolver la tabla ¿tengo que escribir todos los campos a llamar?